# Magento: Filtering reports/product_collection by category seems not to be working

Tags: magento, report

I think this should be an easy problem for anyone who is a little familiar with Magento, but I'm quite new to it and found no solution yet.

I am trying to filter a reports/product_collection which I need to use to get the products ordered by their number of orders by category, example code:

```
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();
$category = 42; // just an example
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter("status", Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)     
                ->setPageSize(9)
                ->setCurPage(1) 
                ->addOrderedQty()
                ->setOrder("ordered_qty", "desc")
                ->setStore($store)
                ->addStoreFilter($store)
                ->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category));
```

Using the addCategoryFilter() method on a catalog/product_collection works fine, but on a reports/product_collection it doesnt seem to do anything, it still queries the produts of all categories.
And by the way, the addAttributeToFilter() method seems not to be working either.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Just a rambling though, but shouldn't it be more like this?
I don't think you're staging your filter correctly. IMHO

```
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();

$category = 42; // just an example

$products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter("status", Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)     
            ->setPageSize(9)
            ->setCurPage(1) 
            ->addOrderedQty()
            ->setOrder("ordered_qty", "desc")
            ->setStore($store)
            ->addStoreFilter($store)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $category));
```

Comment: I will try this, but filtering a catalog/product_collection like this `$products = Mage::getResourceModel("catalog/product_collection")
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*') 
    ->addAttributeToFilter("status", Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED) 
    ->setPageSize(9)
    ->setCurPage(1)->setStore($store)->addStoreFilter($store)    ->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($c));` works fine. Im sorry for the weird layout, I cant handle the text editor for comments

Comment: No, that code doesn't work at all, it creates this error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\1.5.1.0\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php on line 816` I think your suggestion is the deprecated way of filtering by category.

Answer (score 0):

Is the category you're querying set as anchor? I'd think this would cause it to include all subcat's products too.